# Taxes on certain retirement income in Canada for a US citizen / resident of Canada

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, retirement

I receive US military retirement, and Veterans Administration Disability and Social Security.  What is taxed in Canada? Is anything exempt such as the Veterans Disability?

Comment: Do you have any investment income, such as interest earned in a bank? Do you have any Canadian-sourced retirement income? Have you been a resident of Canada for a long time, including when you were working? Have you ever filed taxes in Canada / filed US taxes after you immigrated? These questions could all help provide context for a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Publication 597 by the US IRS](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p597#:%7E:text=services%20were%20rendered.-,Social%20security%20benefits.,is%20exempt%20from%20Canadian%20tax.) says:

> U.S. social security benefits paid to a resident of Canada are taxed in Canada as if they were benefits under the Canada Pension Plan, except that 15% of the amount of the benefit is exempt from Canadian tax.